# Google Script Trigger: Issue with function clearing script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a trigger in google script which runs the functions every monday at 9 AM. However my first lines of code clear the content of the google sheet so it can be replaced by the new information. Now when I create a function out of the first lines of code the function is run repetitively meaning it always clears the content of the google sheets and leaves me with an empty sheet (this is the most plausible explanation for me). According to my understanding of the trigger tool, I can only create a trigger on functions and not entire codes (Is this correct?) - how do I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z500");
  range.clearContent();


function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  var topPath = "";
  sheet.appendRow(["Extracted Folder", "Industry", "Client", "Projectname","Folder (empty/not empty)", "Link to Folder", "Date Created", "Owner"])
  iterateSubFolders(topFolder, topPath, 3)
}

function iterateSubFolders(callingFolder, callingPath, depth) {
  var callingFolderName = callingFolder.getName();
  var callingFolderFullPath = callingPath.toString() + callingFolderName.toString() + "/";
  addRowToSheetForFolder(callingFolder, callingFolderFullPath);
  n=0;
  var childSubFolders = callingFolder.getFolders();
  while ((childSubFolders.hasNext()) && (n < depth) ) {
      var nextSubFolder = childSubFolders.next();
      iterateSubFolders(nextSubFolder, callingFolderFullPath, depth - 1);
  }
  return callingFolderFullPath;
}

function addRowToSheetForFolder(folder, fullFolderPath) {
  data = [
             fullFolderPath.toString(),
             // fullFolderPath.split("/"), Getting weird values when splitted 
             "INDUSTRY",
             "CLIENT",
             "PROJECT",
             folder.getSize(),
             folder.getUrl(),
             folder.getDateCreated(),
             "manuell pflegen",
             folder.getDescription()
         ];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

The code no longer works when i convert the first lines to a function so I left it out

Comment: Correct, a trigger will run the function specified. However, the function called by the trigger can call other functions. I do this in many projects with success.

Comment: When you set the Global variables to a standalone function, how are you calling them?

Answer (score 0):

These lines are in global space so they get called every time any function is called:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z500");
range.clearContent();
```

Comment: I know but how do I solve this? How can I clear all the cells only once and then run the entire code with loops etc. ?

Comment: is `ss.getSheets()[0];` the active sheet?